# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm using the book "DOM Scripting" and followed the code in chapter 8 trying to create a definition list but it wouldn't show up. Chrome console showed the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined
> at displayAbbreviations (displayAbbreviations.js:13)

My code is below. Could anybody help me find out what went wrong？ Thanks a lot!

```
function displayAbbreviations(){
    if(!document.getElementsByTagName) return false;
    if(!document.createElement) return false;
    if(!document.createTextNode) return false; 

    //get all the abbreviations
    var abbreviations=document.getElementsByTagName("abbr");
    if (abbreviations.length<1) return false;
    var defs = new Array();
    //loop through the abbreviations
    for (var i=0; i<abbreviations.length;i++);{
        var current_abbr=abbreviations[i];
        var definition=current_abbr.getAttribute("title");
        var key=current_abbr.lastChild.nodeValue;
        defs[key]=definition; 
    }

//Create the definition list
var dlist=document.createElement("dl");

// loop through the definitions
for (key in defs){
    var definition=defs[key];
//create the definition title
    var dtitle=document.createElement("dt");
    var dtitle_text=document.createTextNode(key);
    dtitle.appendChild(dtitle_text);
//create the definition description
    var ddesc=document.createElement("dd");
    var ddesc_text=document.createTextNode(definition);
    ddesc.appendChild(ddesc_text);
//add them to the definition list
    dlist.appendChild(dtitle);
    dlist.appendChild(ddesc);

}

//create a headline
var header=document.createElement("h2");
var header_text=document.createTextNode("Abbreviations");
header.appendChild(header_text);
// add the headline to the body
document.body.appendChild(header);
//add the definition list to the body
document.body.appendChild(dlist);
}

addLoadEvent(displayAbbreviations);
```

Comment: Your variable `defs` is originally an array but adding values it like an object. Why is that

Comment: @NithinChandran is correct (Nithin you should write that up as answer, but make sure you thoroughly explain the mistake and the fix). The OP will then accept your answer and I'll upvote it for you. You'll get some cred! :-)

Comment: Change `var defs = new Array();` to `var defs = {}` - and then please accept Nithin's answer when they get it typed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem OP had is that he had mistakenly put a break(`;`) in the for loop.
Also there are other mistakes which should be resolved like the `defs` variable is originally declared as an array. Though it is used like an object in the subsequent code

**Corrected code**

```
    var defs = {};
    //loop through the abbreviations
    for (var i=0; i<abbreviations.length;i++){
        var current_abbr=abbreviations[i];
        var definition=current_abbr.getAttribute("title");
        var key=current_abbr.lastChild.nodeValue;
        defs[key]=definition; 
    }
```